# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on simple script

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image

I copied and pasted this script from another stackoverflow question. Here is the JSfiddle they provided. http://jsfiddle.net/LmVRZ/2/

I have a wordpress site, I linked it using wp_enqueue_script and wp_register_script and here is the file –

```
 var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }

    $(function () {
        $('img.switch').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
    });
```

It says this error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on simple script. (anonymous function).

Have no idea what I did wrong, since I copied and pasted directly??

If it helps, heres how I load the script in wordpresss

```
wp_register_script( 'rollover', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/rollover.js' , array( 'jquery' ) );
```

Comment: Can you paste your HTML?

Comment: check if jquery is loaded successfully in your page

Comment: Just out of curiosity have you tried a normal script call (not using WPs register script stuff)? Sometimes CMS' want you to specify what script type is, eg: <script type="text/javascript"....

Comment: usually with wordpress you need to wrap your code with jquery noconflict with something like jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }
    $('img.switch').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
});
```